# Javascript object received as null in mvc controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, controller

Below is my AJAX GET request that is trying to pass few parameters including a javascript object to a mvc controller but the object is always received as null:

```
 var sort =  { column: 'UserName', order: 'desc' };
 var sortParameter = JSON.stringify(sort);

 $.ajax({
       url: '@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Account")',
       cache: false,
       type: 'GET',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       data: { skipRecords: vm.pageIndex * 1000, sortParam: sortParameter },
       success: function (data) {
       }
 });
```

The controller method looks like below:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetUsers(int skipRecords, Sort sortParam, string userName = null)
{

}
```

Also below is the Sort class defined:

```
public class Sort
{
    public string column { get; set; }
    public string order { get; set; }
}
```

If I dont use JSON.stringify and pass just the javascript object, below is the request that gets sent:

```
GET /Account/GetUsers?skipRecords=0&sortParam%5Bcolumn%5D=UserName&sortParam%5Border%5D=desc&_=1408990051727 HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: I think you're passing in a string that happens to have JSON in it, not a `Sort` object.  How about just `sortParam: sort`

Comment: @MikeChristensen Yes I tried this before doing JSON.stringify but the properties are passed as null.

Comment: Can you run Fiddler and paste in the exact HTTP request being sent?  That will probably help people spot the issue.

Comment: @MikeChristensen GET /Account/GetUsers?skipRecords=0&sortParam%5Bcolumn%5D=UserName&sortParam%5Border%5D=desc&_=1408990051727 HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
 var sortParameter =  { column: 'UserName', order: 'desc' };

 $.ajax({
       url: '@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Account")',
       cache: false,
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       data: JSON.stringify({ 
         skipRecords: vm.pageIndex * 1000, 
         sortParam: sortParameter }),
       success: function (data) {
       }
 });
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because if you don't JSON.stringify the entire result, it is passed as a querystring encoded.  You can't pass JSON as a value in a querystring encoded value.

Querystring encoded (Post or Get) looks like:  `a=1&b=2&c=3`

So your querystring would look like `skipRecords=5&sortParam={column:'UserName',order:'desc' }`

MVC Won't double decode querystring and json.

Comment: I tried this but still the object contains null properties.

Comment: Remove the stringify and just pass in the native object.

Comment: @BNL Even on doing so, properties are received as null. I have added the GET request in my question which does show the parameter values though.

Comment: You *CANNOT* send JSON through GET, the default model binder will not handle it (because get is ALWAYS querystring/url encoded).

Comment: POST along with JSON.Stringify works. Can you add type:'POST' in your posted code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use POST and prepend [FromBody] to your 'Sort' object parameter in your action method.

Comment: I have used POST along with JSON.stringify.